# Plotting y=times (as data) versus x=dates in matplotlib: How to format the y-axis for all dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

All the SO answers relating to "plotting times vs. dates" did not help with my problem:
Given two series of datetime data, I want to plot the time part versus the date part.

Using the code below, I get the desired formatting, but only for the first point (of both series).
I can't figure out how to define the y-axis limits (or format) that would work for all dates.

Thanks in advance for pointing out my mistake(s)!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = np.array(
    [( 0, '2021-04-14T07:45:00.000000000', '2021-04-14T22:42:00.000000000'),
     ( 1, '2021-04-15T06:37:00.000000000', '2021-04-15T23:20:00.000000000'),
     ( 2, '2021-04-16T06:45:00.000000000', '2021-04-16T22:45:00.000000000'),
     ( 3, '2021-04-17T06:35:00.000000000', '2021-04-17T23:01:00.000000000'),
     ( 4, '2021-04-18T06:30:00.000000000', '2021-04-18T22:50:00.000000000'),
     ( 5, '2021-04-19T06:14:00.000000000', '2021-04-19T23:05:00.000000000'),
     ( 6, '2021-04-20T07:10:00.000000000', '2021-04-21T00:00:00.000000000'),
     ( 7, '2021-04-21T06:37:00.000000000', '2021-04-21T22:30:00.000000000'),
     ( 8, '2021-04-22T07:25:00.000000000', '2021-04-22T23:40:00.000000000'),
     ( 9, '2021-04-23T06:24:00.000000000', '2021-04-23T23:45:00.000000000')],
     dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('up_dt', '<M8[ns]'), ('down_dt', '<M8[ns]')])

# the actual data comes from a csv, so I use pd for further manipulations
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,7))

line1 = ax1.plot(df.up_dt.dt.date, df.up_dt,
                 label='rise time',
                 marker='^', linewidth=0, color='b')
line2 = ax1.plot(df.down_dt.dt.date, df.down_dt,
                 label='bed time',
                 marker='v', linewidth=0, color='b')

# x_axis ranges & format:
ax1.set_xlim([df.up_dt.min()-pd.DateOffset(days=1),
              df.up_dt.max()+pd.DateOffset(days=1)]);
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

# y_axis ranges & format:
d1 = str(df.up_dt.min().date())+' 00:00'
d2 = str(df.up_dt.min().date())+' 23:59'
y_time = pd.date_range(start=d1, end=d2,freq='H')
ax1.set_ylim([y_time.min(), y_time.max()])

ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(24), interval=2))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

ax1.set_ylabel('Clock Hours')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

VER = """python: 3.7.6 [Windows 10, MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
pandas: 1.2.3; numpy: 1.19.2; matplotlib: 3.3.4"""

plt.title(F'Missing data if y-limit set with "df.<series1>.min()":\n{VER}')

plt.show();
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take out the line where you set the y limits, you see that the y values are datetimes, not just times. So you have a couple of choices:

#### 1) Set all the dates the same date for the time column.

You are hiding the date on the y axis, so this is the quickest replacement in your code. The snippet below only shows the added or changed lines from your code block.

```
import datetime
...
# make a new column with one date and the time from up_dt
df["up_time"] = df.up_dt.apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, d.hour, d.minute, d.second, d.microsecond))
...
# plot using the new time column for the y values
line1 = ax1.plot(df.up_dt.dt.date, df.up_time,
                 label='rise time',
                 marker='^', linewidth=0, color='b')
...
# use the new time column when finding the y limits
d1 = str(df.up_time.min().date())+' 00:00'
d2 = str(df.up_time.min().date())+' 23:59'
```

#### 2) Use decimal representation of time

If you want to strip off just the time portion and not use a fake date for a place-holder, you need to convert it to a number, because time objects are not treated numerically by matplotlib, or for the standard datetime package. Using the pendulum package we can convert a time to decimal representation, here I am converting to hours since midnight. You can replace the tick labels with the clock representation strings.

```
import pendulum as pend
...
# make separate up and time columns
df["up_date"] = df.up_dt.apply(lambda d: d.date())
df["up_time_hr"] = df.up_dt.apply(lambda d: (pend.parse(d.isoformat()).time() - pend.time(0)).seconds/3600)

# plot time vs date using the new columns
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,7))
line1 = ax1.plot(df.up_date, df.up_time_hr)

# example of setting tick labels
ax1.set_yticks([ 6.5, 7, 7.5])
ax1.set_yticklabels(["6:30", "7:00", "7:30"])
```

Comment: Thanks @heidi. I use the first solution as I do not want to add another library to my environment.